# Different div width based on screen size in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I would like to stick with native bootstrap utility classes but I cannot find a proper solution.

I want this section to be 50% for large screens and 75% for small devices:

```
  <div class="col-10 col-xl-8 justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="text-white w-75 shaded-background">
      <h1 class="mb-3">Boost Efficiency and Productivity: Modernize Your Legacy Apps Today!</h1>
      <h2 class="mb-3">Don't let your legacy applications slow down your business.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/literakl/pen/XWyjdMo

There is no class `w-xl-50` like with `col`. I am considering `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)` as a workaround if there is no way to use `xl` selector. Better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `w-75` and use `col-9 col-lg-6` instead.

`col-9` declares `width: 75%` and `col-lg-6` declares `width: 50%` at the large breakpoint (min-width: 992px)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  .shaded-background {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="text-white col-9 col-lg-6 shaded-background">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Boost Efficiency and Productivity: Modernize Your Legacy Apps Today!</h1>
    <h2 class="mb-3">Don't let your legacy applications slow down your business.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```